# Reference transaction with Recurring PayPal payment profiles

Tags: php, reference, paypal

I want to modify my billing cycle of recurring payment with a different amount before the next billing cycle starts, and I was suggested that I should use reference transaction for that. But as we know recurring payment profile call does not respond with transaction id then how is it possible to make a reference transaction ?
Please help me with this subject.

Thank You,

Comment: is this by any chance related to PayPal?

Comment: Yes, Fred. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: I modified your title and tag. You should get more response that way. Cheers

Comment: To reference the recurring payment you have set up, you will need to reference the profile id instead. Here is something to get your started: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/getrecurringpaymentsprofiledetails-api-operation-nvp

Comment: I tried the profile id as a reference for reference transaction but it's not working. Can you suggest me the way to get the Latest transaction Id for a ongoing billing cycle.

Comment: @Cumbo Thank you for your support. But still the problem is not resolved. We can't not use profile Id as reference Id. We require transaction id for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with a recurring payments profile created via Payments Pro or Express Checkout then you'll need to update it using [UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/updaterecurringpaymentsprofile-api-operation-nvp).  You could also do it manually via the PayPal account.

If the profile was setup using a credit card there aren't any limitations to updating the amount.  Unfortunately, if the profile was setup using a PayPal account you can only increase the amount by 20% every 180 days.

That's probably why reference transactions were recommended.  Using reference transactions you can build your own recurring payments system and avoid this limitation.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your reply. I want to use my own recurring payment system using Reference transaction. But I didn't found any way to set Billing Cycle, Billing Frequency.

Comment: I have an added requirement as I want to give discount to a profile holder for a particular month without disturbing the actual amount of the billing cycle. Is it possible with PayPal. If yes then How ??

Comment: Well, you're confusing the two.  If you're going to build your own recurring system with the use of reference transactions then you wouldn't be passing any billing cylce or frequency to PayPal.  That would all be handled within your own application.  You'd need to setup a script to run every day (possibly multiple times per day) that would loop through all your local profile data and submit the DoReferenceTransaction request for all profiles that were due that day.  Again, you would handle this logic on your own since you're not going to use PayPal's actual recurring payments system.

Comment: Also, since building it on your own you could easily add logic to your automated script(s) that run each day to skip payment for somebody that you'd like to give a free month, or whatever.  You'll be handling all of that logic within your application.  That's what building your own system would consist of.

Comment: Thanks Andrew that's definitely gonna help me in solving my problem.